# Bubble plot corresponding dot negative and positive values in R

Tags: r, plot, gdal, gstat

I want to plot bubbles of my data.

Here is what I already have:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
require(gstat)
setwd("C:/Users/49151/Desktop")

#import data
data <- read.csv("kerpentest0909x.csv")

head(data)

hist(data$Z, breaks = 20, xlab = "subsidence rates (mm/year)", main = "Histogram of subsidence at Kreuz Kerpen")
summary(data$Z)

#if slght skewedness 
#data$Z.1 <- log10(data$Z)
#hist(data$Z.1, breaks = 10, xlab = "subsidence rates (mm/year)", main = "Histogram of subsidence at Kreuz Kerpen")

#convert data
coordinates(data) <- c("X", "Y")
#assigning projection
proj4string(data) <-CRS("+init=epsg:32632")

plot(data, asp=1, pch=1)

plot(data, asp=1, cex=4*data$Z/max(data$Z), pch=1)
```

The plot function gives me this:

[image]

It shows me just the high positive values.
However I lack the R experience to do the following:
Showing me both high negative and high positive values and a color distinction between both.
If possible I'd like to see the values at each dot.
here is my data:https://ufile.io/lne90ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using `sf` and `ggplot2`...
To make the plot visually clearer, have added colour to the points and set `alpha` to 0.5 as the plot is quite crowded. You can easily edit the appearance to suit your needs.

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

#import data
data <- read.csv("kerpentest0909x.csv")

data1 <- 
  st_as_sf(data, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 32632)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = data1, aes(size = Z, fill = Z), shape = 21, alpha = 0.5)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This helped alot! why did you mutated the data by dividing it by max(Z) for plotting?

Comment: This is what was done in the question, this code line refers: `plot(data, asp=1, cex=4*data$Z/max(data$Z), pch=1)` Have edited the answer to remove this as it is not needed.

Comment: my apologies, forget to clean the code. this was from an way older version of the complete code.